# Creating a different layout for a Webview

Tags: android, layout, webview, android-webview

I was trying to make an app using Android `Webview`. I am able to use `Webview` to load my site. My site is for registered users only. As a result, I wanted to create a `Webview` only for my logged in users. So, one layout (empty) for login page and another(tabbed) for logged in user.

So, is it possible to have 2 different layouts in a `Webview` in the same app? I am new in Android Studio and did not find specific discussion/solution of this problem elsewhere.

Share your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: you want load your website in webview then user can login in one tab & and show logged website in another website?

Comment: You already use `Webview` to load your website why don't you just load your Login page first? After user login, they will eventually go to registered users only content.

Comment: My login page is the landing page, so I loaded that in webview(without any tabbed). Now, when logged in user view the inner pages they would see the   pages with tabbed webview layout. How can I achieve that?